# Parse a value using string

Tags: java, regex

I am reading a file using BufferedReader and I am trying to parse out a string using regex.
The string that I would like to parse looks like this,

```
<test>123</test>
```

And, there should be text before and end of this string.  And, I just want to parse the value of this string (Ex.  I want to grab "123" in this case from the read string).

Regex I have is very simple, looks like

```
<test>?
```

I guess this is wrong, since it doesn't work.  :)

Can somebody show me how to parse a such value from the string using the regex?

Thanks.

Comment: I added the java tag since I think that's the only language with BufferedReader.

Comment: Does it matter what is before and after "123", or can it be enough that there is text before and end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what technology you are using. Anyway, a pattern matching the test node is:

```
<test>(\d*)</test>     //only digits, empty string is mathced

<test>([a-zA-Z0-9\s]*)</test>     //a more general character class
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?31idq)

Comment: Ah okay.  thanks everyone.  Sorry that I wasnt clear.  I am using Java and the expression works.  thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified a language, but this should work:

```
/<test>([^<]+)<\/test>/
```

The string you are looking for will be in the first captured group.